# What are these layers that prevent me from editing my artboards?

Tags: sketch-app

I have noticed in some projects some strange layers that go over the artboard. It prevents you from making changes until they are deleted - what are they?

[image: layers over top of artboard]

I haven't seen them in any of my projects before.

Comment: I think these are slices made using the slice tool.  See the user manual for more info: https://www.sketch.com/docs/importing-and-exporting/#how-to-use-slices

Comment: @BillyKerr You're right, yes. This is what it is. Thanks. You should make this an answer so it can be cleared.